# Yii2 - DynamicModel validator attribute when not working

Tags: php, forms, validation, yii2

I am trying to use Yii2's conditional validator within DynamicModel clas, but the validator when is not working:

**Controller**

```
private function createFormModel(){
    
    $model = new DynamicModel([
        'indicador',
        'departamento',
        'mes'
    ]);

    $model->addRule(['indicador'],'required',['message' => 'Este campo es obligatorio']);    
    $model->addRule(['departamento'], 'required', ['when' => function ($model) {
        return $model->indicador == 'Semana';
    }]);            

    return $model;
}

public function actionCuatrimestre()
{
    $model = $this->createFormModel();

    return $this->render('cuatrimestre',[
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Whether I select or not the "indicador" field which is a select field, the "departamento" field alwasys returns as required. I have algo try this way but with no results:

```
$model->addRule(['departamento'], 'required', ['when' => function ($model) {
    return $model->indicador == 'Semana';
}], ['whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
return $('#indicador').val() == 'Semana';
}"]);
```

What I am missing here?

**EDIT**

My view code cuatrimestre.php

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>         
<div class="form-group">
    <?=  $form->field($model, 'indicador')->widget(Select2::class, [
        'options' => ['id'=>'indicador'],
        'data' => ['Semana','Día','Resumen'],
    ]); ?>    
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?=  $form->field($model, 'departamento')->widget(Select2::class, [
        'options' => ['id'=>'departamento'],
        'data' => Departamentos::getDepartamentosByUser(),       
    ]); ?>    
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'curso')->widget(DepDrop::class, [
        'type' => DepDrop::TYPE_SELECT2,
        'options' => ['id' => 'curso-id'],
        'select2Options' => ['pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true]],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'depends' => ['departamento-id'],
            'placeholder'=>'Seleccionar curso',
            'url' => Url::to(['/campus-actividad/subcursos']),
            'loadingText' => 'Cargando ...',
            'initialize' => true,
        ]
    ]);?>  
</div>
<div>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Aplicar filtros', ['class' => 'btn btn-block btn-default']) ?>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: In the case with `whenClient` option you are passing it in array as 4th parameter but `DynamicModel::addRule()` only accepts 3 params. Try putting it in same array where your `when` option is.

Comment: No results! I will add my view code! I dont get why it doesnt work out!